# Powershell (cmd) is not connected with atom

Tags: powershell, cmd, atom-editor

[I have download packages many Times and it didnt work.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0si1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKNJm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run a Python script. Try running it with:

```
python ./ex_04_06.py
```

Comment: Thank You . It is correct. I am running Python script. When I hit ./ex_04_06.py I got to cmd and then I ran the code but on the end the window(CMD) is dissapearing and I can not see the result. I should mention that there is a problem on the start of atom-editor :"Faild to instal powershell dependencies" . I download packages and install them in cmd and it seems to looks that atom-editor don't have them. Thank You for answear.